# magento newsletter preview perfect but when receiving it, the newsletter changes

Tags: magento, newsletter

I am using Magento 1.6.2.0
I set a Newsletter template on the magento, and add the newsletter to the queue.
When I preview the newsletter everything is perfect, and then the newsletter is sent.
When I see the newsletter in my email account, The newsletter changes , such as the img shifts.
Any idea why? How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the issue happen in multiple email clients or just Outlook for example? You really should post code...

Comment: It happens for all actually.

Answer (score 0):

Newsletter rendering in email clients can differ a lot from what you see in your browser when you launch a preview, because it obey to different rules. Check this link for more informations :  http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/guidelines/

Comment: Thank you very much blmage! I found out that the problem is <a href="URL">
</a>. Every img and text with link. In the email there will be a space around them. Do you know how I can prevent this?

Comment: I know that `style="display:block;"` must be applied to `img` tags, but that's almost all, as I never had myself to integrate a newsletter. Perhaps you can find more informations in the guides available here : http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/ and here : http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/

Comment: I already used style="display:block;", But Thanks for the link.a

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, always use `display:block;` around images. In addition, in 99% of cases, you should have the images in their own table cell, separate from text and other images.

I'm speculating without seeing the code, but my first guess is try putting this in your header style tags:

`p {margin: 1em 0;}`